# jQuery FileUpload: Ajax freezes the browser when uploading images (jpg, png)

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I use jQuery Fileupload plugin for uploading files (.pdf,.zip,.dll and .png/.jpg) to server from local. All of file types above can be uploaded successfully on major browsers Chrome/Firefox/IE, except .png/.jpg.

When trying to upload the .png/.jpg on Chrome, the upload plugin will freeze this browser for 10-15 minutes until the ajax of sending data of XHR object is done, even the size of image is quite small (~90Kb). On contrast, the same process just takes 1-2 seconds to be done on FF/IE.

I am using v5.9 of this plugin with these overwrite options:

```
var maxFileSize = 500000000000000;
var resizeMaxWidth = 1920;
var resizeMaxHeight = 1200;
var maxChunkSize = 1073741824;
var maxNumberOfFiles = 1;

$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
    forceIframeTransport: true,
    maxFileSize: maxFileSize,
    resizeMaxWidth: resizeMaxWidth,
    resizeMaxHeight: resizeMaxHeight,
    maxChunkSize: maxChunkSize,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    acceptFileTypes: regularExpression,
    autoUpload: autoUpload
});
```

I tried to set `async: true;` to force browser not to freeze the page, but failed.

and I got freezing page on Chrome when the scripts run to _onSend() event and can not return "success" callback.

```
_onSend: function (e, data) {  
        var that = this,
            jqXHR,
            slot,
            pipe,
            options = that._getAJAXSettings(data),
            send = function (resolve, args) {
                that._sending += 1;
                jqXHR = jqXHR || (
                    (resolve !== false &&
                    that._trigger('send', e, options) !== false &&
                    (that._chunkedUpload(options) || $.ajax(options))) ||
                    that._getXHRPromise(false, options.context, args)
                ).success(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    that._onDone(result, textStatus, jqXHR, options);
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    that._onFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, options);
                }).always(function (jqXHRorResult, textStatus, jqXHRorError) {
                    that._sending -= 1;
                    that._onAlways(
                        jqXHRorResult,
                        textStatus,
                        jqXHRorError,
                        options
                    );
                    if (options.limitConcurrentUploads &&
                            options.limitConcurrentUploads > that._sending) {
                        // Start the next queued upload,
                        // that has not been aborted:
                        var nextSlot = that._slots.shift();
                        while (nextSlot) {
                            if (!nextSlot.isRejected()) {
                                nextSlot.resolve();
                                break;
                            }
                            nextSlot = that._slots.shift();
                        }
                    }
                });
                return jqXHR;
            };
        this._beforeSend(e, options);
        if (this.options.sequentialUploads ||
                (this.options.limitConcurrentUploads &&
                this.options.limitConcurrentUploads <= this._sending)) {
            if (this.options.limitConcurrentUploads > 1) {
                slot = $.Deferred();
                this._slots.push(slot);
                pipe = slot.pipe(send);
            } else {
                pipe = (this._sequence = this._sequence.pipe(send, send));
            }
            // Return the piped Promise object, enhanced with an abort method,
            // which is delegated to the jqXHR object of the current upload,
            // and jqXHR callbacks mapped to the equivalent Promise methods:
            pipe.abort = function () {
                var args = [undefined, 'abort', 'abort'];
                if (!jqXHR) {
                    if (slot) {
                        slot.rejectWith(args);
                    }
                    return send(false, args);
                }
                return jqXHR.abort();
            };
            return this._enhancePromise(pipe);
        }
        return send();
    },
```

Do you know how to force this plugin's Ajax to run on Chrome as it does on Firefox/IE ? or any hints to fix this issue ?

Thank you !

Cheers,

Comment: It's difficult to say something without code.

Comment: Can we see some code please?